# Se puede combinar el framework HaMeR con RxJava

Tags: android, rxjava

Hola a todas las personas del foro, buscando en internet para mejorar mis aplicaciones android, me encontre con el tema de concurrencia, una buena practica que se puede realiar con el "Framework" HaMeR, y poco tiempo despues me tope con RxJava, mi duda es si al querer implementar RxJava, estaria de más combinarlo HaMeR.
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión el uso de HaMeR esta bien si quieres prescindir de librerias de tercero, pero si no tienes problema en usar RxJava seguramente te solucionara las cosas mas facilmente. A tu preguntar sobre si una cosa excluye la otra, podrías usar ambas cosas pero creo que resulta redundante pues se persigue el mismo objetivo.